# How can I add an await to the region to the right of the || in "if (count == 0 || await MainPage.DisplayAlert"

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public async Task ReviewAppAsync(int count)
{
    await Task.Delay(60000);
    if (count == 0 || await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Review", "abc", "Yes", "No"))
    {
            //  some code here
    }
}
```

I would only like to wait if count is not zero.

How can I move the first await Task.Delay(60000);

so that it  only  delays:   MainPage.DisplayAlert("Review", "abc", "Yes", "No"))?

Comment: Do you have to `await` in this method, can you maybe return a Task - based on count - from this method and let the caller await ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet here is to refactor it a bit - perhaps via a local function:

```cs
public async Task ReviewAppAsync(int count)
{
    async Task<bool> DelayAndDisplayAlert()
    {
        await Task.Delay(60000);
        return await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Review", "abc", "Yes", "No");
    }

    if (count == 0 || await DelayAndDisplayAlert())
    {
        //  some code here
    }
}
```

There *are ways* of doing it without the extra call, but... they'll be messy and ugly; moving the pieces into a separate method is much cleaner. If you're using an older version of C#, you may need to move `DelayAndDisplayAlert` outside of the method:

```cs
async Task<bool> DelayAndDisplayAlert()
{
    await Task.Delay(60000);
    return await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Review", "abc", "Yes", "No");
}
public async Task ReviewAppAsync(int count)
{
    if (count == 0 || await DelayAndDisplayAlert())
    {
        //  some code here
    }
}
```